# Is static keyword necessary both in functions' prototype and definition in C?

Tags: c, static

I read in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15670259/5410078) how to use `static` specifier for functions in C, but I did not understand if it is necessary to use it both in a function's prototype and definition or it can be omitted in the definition. For example, in this case:

```
static void foo(void);

void foo() {...}
```

has the `foo` only an *internal linkage* or such usage is incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> has the foo only an internal linkage or such usage is incorrect?

[6.2.2 Linkage of identifier](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.2p4) states:

> For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier extern in a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible,31) if the prior declaration specifies internal or external linkage, the linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the same as the linkage specified at the prior declaration.

When the `foo` definition says it has external linkage (functions have external linkage if none specified explicitly<sup>1</sup>) and at that point, there was a prior declaration of `foo` with internal linkage is visible. So `foo` has internal linkage.

[<sup>1</sup>](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.2p5):

> If the declaration of an identifier for a function has no storage-class specifier, its linkage is determined exactly as if it were declared with the storage-class specifier extern. If the declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and no storage-class specifier, its linkage is external.

Answer (score 0):

In C whole functions have default external linkage. If you use static keyword for the function. It changes the linkage from external linkage to internal internal linkage. You can use "static" keyword for the function to be available for just the file which is defined in. That's all.

```
static void foo(void); // internal linkage

void foo(void);        // external linkage
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which was about declaration and definition having mismatching linkage specifiers.

Comment: exactly, my question was related to definition and declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage is perfectly OK. `foo` will be known only in the current source file being compiled.