# Is the static keyword needed in both the declaration and the definition of a static function in C?

Tags: c, static

In C, inside a implementation file, when forward declaring a static function in that same file, is the static keyword needed in both the declaration (prototype) and the definition of the function?

Comment: João Pires, Curious: why would one want them different?

Comment: Don't know, but I can't find no definite answer to this while Googling. I'm using static on both.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does a static function need the static keyword for the prototype in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670010/does-a-static-function-need-the-static-keyword-for-the-prototype-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include `static` in the prototype (forward declaration), then you can omit that keyword in the actual definition (it is then implied). However, if you *do not* have `static` in the prototype but *do* include it in the definition, then you are in the realms of non-Standard C.

For example, the following code is non-standard:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void); // This declares a non-static function.

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}

static void foo(void)
{
    printf("Foo!\n");
}
```

The clang-cl compiler warns about this:

> warning : redeclaring non-static 'foo' as static is a Microsoft
> extension [-Wmicrosoft-redeclare-static]